# Typescript enums typing error (argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum define as follows:

```
export enum taskTypes {
  WORK = 'work',
  SLEEP = 'sleep',
  EXERCISE = 'exercise',
  EAT = 'eat'
}
```

On the top of my class I define the `currentTask` as follows:

```
private currentTask: string;
```

However, when I use the enums in `[WORK, SLEEP].includes(currentTask)` I get the following error.

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'currentTask'`

The weird thing is when I simply just change it to use the actual string it doesn't complain.

`['work', 'sleep'].includes(currentTask)` ===> this works.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`currentTask` is of type string, but `WORK` and `SLEEP` is enum members of type `taskTypes`

So `[WORK, SLEEP]` is an array of `taskTypes` enums. Such an array can never contain a string.

`['work', 'sleep']` is an array of strings, which can contain a string.

If you type the private memeber to be of type `taskTypes` it will also work

```
private currentTask: taskTypes
```

Comment: Ah, I see, one question though, type `taskTypes` is an enum which is type string right?

Comment: @honeybadger_execute no, enums and strings are different types in TypeScript. "String enums" are a special case of enums, that "serialize" well (e.g. log), but still not the same as strings. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html